# libnl-3 not recognised during net-snmp make process

Tags: linux, net-snmp, netlink

I have been trying to make net-snmp, I've overcome most of the issues I've had but I can't figure this one out.

During the make process using the Makefile that is included with the package source files, I get the following error:
`mibgroup/if-mib/data_access/interface_linux.c:27:2: error: #error libnl-3 is required. Please install the libnl-3 and libnl-route-3 development packages and remove --without-nl from the configure options if necessary. 27 | #error libnl-3 is required. Please install the libnl-3 and libnl-route-3 development packages and remove --without-nl from the configure options if necessary.`

I have libnl-3-dev and libnl-route-3-dev packages installed.

It would appear that the make process is expecting a collection of header files to be located in: /usr/include/netlink
However the header files are actually located in:
/usr/include/libnl3/netlink.

When inspecting the header files, it would appear that these also reference header files in /usr/include/netlink so they too seem to be pointing to the wrong location.

I have attempted to setup a symbolic link between /usr/include/libnl3/netlink and /usr/include/netlink (shot in the dark) but this didn't help.

I have also attempted to point everything to /usr/include/libnl3/netlink by modifying the Makefile and header files.  I thought I was getting somewhere with this but eventually I ended up with the same error so I purged the install, reinstalled to revert the header files and cloned a clean copy of net-snmp (everything back to the original state).

I've also tried using pkg-config and added a new package search path but (if that statement didn't already give it away) I'm new to the pkg-config and it didn't make a difference.

Any help would be greatly appreciate.